# AWS EB Auto Scale Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling, amazon-elb

When I set up my EB environment, it created a custom AMI, a load balancer, and an auto scaling group for that load balancer.

I needed to add another domain to be serviced by this EB environment, so I added another load balancer in the EC2 console, added the SSL cert for that domain, and put one of the EC2 instances behind that load balancer.

Now I need to make sure the Auto Scaling group that EB created for me has both load balancers in it, however I found out that you can't add or remove load balancers for Auto Scaling groups. So I tried creating a new Auto Scaling group with everything exactly the same as the one that EB created, except with 2 load balancers, but whenever it tries to launch the custom AMI that EB created in this new Auto Scaling group, it fails with the message:

> "The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet.
>   Launching EC2 instance failed."

So then I thought about modifying the custom AMI that EB created to get rid of the groupName parameter, but apparently you can't modify an AMI that EB created? What am I left to do here?

Comment: Maybe you should instead try to explain your end goal. Why would you possibly want two load balancers on a single environment? Couldn't you just set up domain forwarding? Or Clone the environment?

Comment: The end goal is to have 2 domains be served by the same autoscaling group.

Comment: Thats not a  end goal, that's a possible solution. Why do you want this? What is your use case? Why is standard solutions like domain  forwarding not good enough? Why is running two identical environments not a solution? Why do you even need two separate domains if the content is the  same?

Comment: The majority of the domains are the same (database, layouts, etc.) but there are some slightly different views and layouts. Domain forwarding isn't sufficient because we don't want the destination domain to show up.

Comment: Wait, so there are differences? How would two autoscaling groups even solve your problem if there are differences? Or is the beanstalk environment just a backend? The destination domain doesn't have to show up, you can set the beanstalk URL as a cname. You can even set up forward with masking to your original domain.